# Can GHC warn if class instance is a loop?

Tags: haskell

Real World Haskell has this example:

```
class BasicEq3 a where
    isEqual3 :: a -> a -> Bool
    isEqual3 x y = not (isNotEqual3 x y)

    isNotEqual3 :: a -> a -> Bool
    isNotEqual3 x y = not (isEqual3 x y) 

instance BasicEq3 Bool
```

And when I run it in GHCI:

```
#> isEqual3 False False
out of memory
```

So, you have to implement at least one of the 2 methods or it will loop.  And you get the flexibility of choosing which one, which is neat.

The question I have is, is there a way to get a warning or something if didn't override enough of the defaults and the defaults form a loop?  It seems strange to me that the compiler that is so crazy smart is fine with this example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's perfectly fine for GHC to issue a warning in case of an "unbroken" cyclic dependency. There's even a ticket along those lines: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6028

Just because something is "undecidable" doesn't mean no instance of the problem can be solved effectively. GHC (or any other Haskell compiler) already has quite a bit of the information it needs, and it'd be perfectly possible for it to issue a warning if the user is instantiating a class without "breaking" the cyclic dependency. And if the compiler gets it wrong in the rare cases as exemplified in previous posts, then the user can have a `-nowarnundefinedcyclicmethods` or a similar mechanism to tell GHC to be quiet. In nearly every other case, the warning will be most welcome and would add to programmer productivity; avoiding what's almost always a silly bug.

Comment: Yes! In the case of the halting problem, total languages like Agda prove that problems that are unsolvable in general can have large and interesting solvable subsets.

Comment: " 'just plain undecidable' isn't sufficient criterion for dismissing out of hand a compiler technique. Most undecidable problems that are undecidable in the general case are quite decidable in specific cases." http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SufficientlySmartCompiler

Comment: The trac ticket has been closed for a nonsense reason: someone might define a `Num` instance without `-` or `negate` but where `+` doesn't evaluate its second argument, so its apparently circular definition would terminate fine. This always-discarding-second-argument is the only way to get out of the non-termination without defining `-` or `negate`. I think these are bizzare use cases, and it's fine to have to specify `-noarnundefinedcyclicmethods` if you want to escape circular definitions by using `_`. I have _no idea_ how to raise that on trac though.

Answer (score 12):

No, I'm afraid GHC doesn't do anything like that. Also that isn't possible *in general*.

You see, the methods of a type class could be mutually recursive in a useful way. Here's a contrived example of such a type class. It's perfectly fine to not define either `sumOdds` or `sumEvens`, even though their default implementations are in terms of each other.

```
class Weird a where
    measure :: a -> Int

    sumOdds :: [a] -> Int
    sumOdds [] = 0
    sumOdds (_:xs) = sumEvens xs

    sumEvens :: [a] -> Int
    sumEvens [] = 0
    sumEvens (x:xs) = measure x + sumOdds xs
```

Comment: Interesting, I never thought of that.

Comment: In fact, many standard classes do that (`Ord`, for example). That's where "minimal complete definition" comes from.

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't, since if the compiler could make this determination, that would be equivalent to solving the Halting Problem. In general, the fact that two functions call each other in a "loop" pattern is not enough to conclude that actually calling one of the functions will result in a loop.

To use a (contrived) example,

```
collatzOdd :: Int -> Int
collatzOdd 1 = 1
collatzOdd n = let n' = 3*n+1 in if n' `mod` 2 == 0 then collatzEven n'
                                   else collatzOdd n'

collatzEven :: Int -> Int
collatzEven n = let n' = n `div` 2 in if n' `mod` 2 == 0 then collatzEven n'
                                        else collatzOdd n'

collatz :: Int -> Int
collatz n = if n `mod` 2 == 0 then collatzEven n else collatzOdd n
```

(This is of course not the most natural way to implement the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), but it illustrates mutually recursive functions.)

Now `collatzEven` and `collatzOdd` depend on each other, but the Collatz conjecture states that calling `collatz` terminates for all positive `n`. If GHC could determine whether a class that had `collatzOdd` and `collatzEven` as default definitions had a complete definition or not, then GHC would be able to solve the Collatz conjecture! (This is of course not a proof of the undecideability of the Halting Problem, but it should illustrate why determining whether a mutually recursive set of functions is well-defined is not at all as trivial as it may seem.)

In general, since GHC cannot determine this automatically, documentation for Haskell classes will give the "minimal complete definition" necessary for creating an instance of a class.

Comment: It would be nice if there was some way of specifying the minimal complete definition in such a way that the compiler could check it, though.

Comment: That's a good point - perhaps a compiler pragma with the class definition.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. I worry that you're expecting the compiler to solve the halting problem! Just because two functions are defined in terms of each other, doesn't mean it's a bad default class. Also, I've used classes in the past where I just needed to write `instance MyClass MyType` to add useful functionality. So asking the compiler to warn you about that class is asking it to complain about other, valid code.

[Of course, use ghci during development and test every function after you've written it! 
Use [HUnit](http://hunit.sourceforge.net/) and/or [QuickCheck](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck), just to make sure none of this stuff ends up in final code.]

Answer (score 2):

In my personal opinion, the defaulting mechanism is unnecessary and unwise. It would be easy for the class author to just provide the defaults as ordinary functions:

```
notEq3FromEq3 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> (a -> a -> Bool)
notEq3FromEq3 eq3 = (\x y -> not (eq3 x y))

eq3FromNotEq3 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> (a -> a -> Bool)
eq3FromNotEq3 ne3 = (\x y -> not (ne3 x y))
```

(In fact, these two definitions are equal, but that would not be true in general). Then an instance looks like:

```
 instance BasicEq3 Bool where
   isEqual3 True True = True
   isEqual3 False False = True
   isEqual3 _ _ = False

   isNotEqual3 = notEq3FromEq3 isEqual3
```

and no defaults are required. Then GHC can warn you if you don't provide the definition, and any unpleasant loops have to be explicitly written by you into your code.

This does remove the neat ability to add new methods to a class with default definitions without affecting existing instances, but that's not so huge a benefit in my view. The above approach is also in principle more flexible: you could e.g. provide functions that allowed an `Ord` instance to choose *any* comparison operator to implement.