# Avoiding a bug with mutually recursive default methods in type classes

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can GHC warn if class instance is a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270239/can-ghc-warn-if-class-instance-is-a-loop)

Consider a type class with two methods which are implementable in terms of each other:

```
class Num a => Foo a where

  foo :: a

  bar :: a -> a
  bar x = baz x + 1

  baz :: a -> a
  baz x = bar x - 1
```

Depending on the type, it might be easier to implement `bar` or `baz`, or you might want to give implementations of both of them for efficiency reasons.

Now I go somewhere else and make an instance of this class

```
instance Foo Integer where
  foo = 1
```

Oops, I forgot to implement *either* of `bar` or `baz`! Never mind, the type system will pick that up for me, won't it?

```
C:\path\to\file> ghci Foo.hs
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

Hmm, apparently not. Now if I try to use my class

```
*Main> bar 1
<interactive>: out of memory
```

Uh oh. Cue hours of painful debugging.

Is there a way to let GHC know that each instance needs to specify *at least one* of `bar` or `baz`?

Comment: relevant: [Can ghc warn if class instance is a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270239/can-ghc-warn-if-class-instance-is-a-loop)

Comment: @AndrewC Thanks. I've voted to close as a duplicate, but I think there's a subtle difference in my question - I don't want the compiler to *always* complain about mutually recursive defaults, but I *do* want the option to tell it to complain for particular classes.

Comment: I guess it is worth human specification, yes, since asking the compiler to spot where mutual recursion is circular rather than useful is asking a lot! Perhaps a pragma asking it to warn that at least one (sometimes two) of a set of functions is redefined when you make an instance (hard to specify, spread out), or perhaps better, a list of alternative minimal specifications (could be in one large pragma in one place - better). I haven't read the [trac ticket](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6028) closely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Most libraries that define type classes with defaults will specify a "minimal complete definition", but they don't specify that to GHC in a checkable way right now. There's been some vague talk of implementing a pragma for this, but nothing serious as far as I know.

Note that just checking for mutual recursion isn't sufficient; mutually recursive default methods might be perfectly valid, e.g. `some` and `many` in [`Alternative`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html#g:2).